# How can I add my ACF field into another plugin's form

Tags: wordpress

How can I add my ACF field into another plugin's form?

I tried this but this does not work

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="deal_title"><?php _e('Deal title', 'wcd'); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="deal_title" id="deal_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr($deal_title) ?>" class="form-control" data-validation="required"  data-error="<?php esc_attr_e('Please input deal description', 'wcd'); ?>">
    <p class="description"><?php _e('Input title for the deal.', 'wcd'); ?></p>
</div>

//This is the part I want my ACF field
<?php echo the_field('business_name'); ?>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="deal_description" data-error="<?php esc_attr_e('Please type description of the deal', 'wcd'); ?>"><?php _e('Deal Description', 'wcd'); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <?php wp_editor($deal_description, 'deal_description'); ?>
    <p class="description"><?php _e('Input description of the deal.', 'wcd'); ?></p>
</div>
```

How will this be achieved?

Comment: This is not the correct solution , it will provide you with value of business_name ... Visit this link for a detailed solution : http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: The field that I must add should be associated with the product. At the backend I have the form. When I add a product from front end, its value should be visible at the backend too, nut i'm unable to do it.

Comment: yes, acf_form() is a function which accepts arguments to tell that function that for which post_type you want a form at frontend... check this out http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/

Comment: I'm a total newbie. Can you help he with that a bit?

Comment: wait lemme write an asnwer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new template and assign that to a page..

Now in that template copy this code :

> You have to change 2 things in below code 1. YOUR_POST_TYPE , 2. YOUR
>   FIELD GROUP

***Field group can be achieved by editing any field group (its ID will be in the top).***

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id )
{
    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' )
    {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish' ,
        'post_title'  => $_POST['fields']['title'] ,
        'post_type'  => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' ,
    );  

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post ); 

    // update $_POST['return']
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );    

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );
?>
            <div id="content" class="clearfix row">

                <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 clearfix" role="main">

                    <?php 
                    acf_form(array(
                        'field_groups'        => array('YOUR FIELD GROUP'),
                        'post_id'       => 'new',
                        'submit_value'      => 'Submit Product'
                )); ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main -->

                <?php //get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>

            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Actually I have to insert the fields in wc deals plugin. So I just copy this code over there in the html part?

Comment: If you want only one field to be inserted from front end then manually create a html input tag and insert the records to the desired table ..
Please find the links to add records in the Wp_posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Insert records in wp_post_meta https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: Yes i know how to add a single field but my scenario is a bit different. I have added the group fields (by ACF) in products at backend. I want those exact fields to come on the front end too (just by passing their id or something) and save their value in ACF.

Comment: You want the fields in wc deals plugin or frontend ??

Comment: wc deals plugin. At the front end. When I click Submit deal, a form appears and in that form I want that field. This stuff is happening at the front end actually.

Comment: Okay , try using this plugin ... https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-front-end-form-extension/  and in the plugin page in php write `<?php echo do_shortcode( [acf_form group_id="x"]);?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100548/discussion-between-ali-zia-and-prakash-rao).